# Input Field value retrieval on button click php

Tags: php

I am trying to access the value of an Input field. and passing it on to the new query

```
<div class="form-group">

                      <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <input type="text" name="storename" value="" class="validate[required] form-control" placeholder="Store name">
                        <a class="btn btn-danger" href="store.php">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Search Store&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
                      </div>
                             <script type="text/javascript">
                                $('a.btn-danger').click(function () {
                                    window.location.href = $(this).attr('href') + '?name=' + $(this).prev('input').val();
                                });
                            </script>

                    </div>
```

Comment: Are you using submit button ?

Comment: I am using  <a class="btn btn-danger"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use java script to access value.

Have a look: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_textarea_value.asp

Answer (score 0):

Well, is there anything in the query string when you try this?  If there's no `storename` value *in the URL* when the request is made to the server to initially load this page, then that value is going to be blank.

You're mixing server-side and client-side concerns.  The PHP code is evaluated server-side when this page is requested, before the user sees the page.  Once the user is on the page and inputting a value into that `input` element, the PHP code is long gone and can't execute anymore.

You can, however, modify your `href` with client-side code.  For example, if you're using jQuery, you might do something like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <input type="text" name="storename" value="" class="validate[required] form-control" placeholder="Store name">
    <a class="btn btn-danger" href="store.php">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Search Store&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('a.btn-danger').click(function () {
        window.location.href = $(this).attr('href') + '?name=' + $(this).prev('input').val();
    });
</script>
```

This intercepts the click on the link and manually sets the window's location to that link + a query string value with the user's input value in the previous text input.

Comment: check the edit. I have tried this but the herf is not appending ?name= etc

Comment: @MuhammadUmar: Are you referencing jQuery?  If not then you'll either need to add it or do this in plain JavaScript (or in any other library you might be using).  Are there any errors on your JavaScript console?  If you put a debugging breakpoint in this function with your JavaScript debugger, does it find the values you expect?